# How to attach textfile with mail in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am developing one iPhone application using Objective-C in which I have to send e-mails by attaching a text file with that. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Hi take a look at this

```
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[composer setSubject:@"Subject"];
NSString *fullPath =//get path of the file
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
[composer addAttachmentData:fileData 
                 mimeType:@"text/plain" 
                 fileName:@"File_Name"];        
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithString:@"Body"];
[composer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
[composer release];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a mail composer view controller:

```
[mailComposerViewController addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"name_of_text_file"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a working code in my app..SO just follow along.
The file(text file) is in my documents directory of the app
Make sure you have added MessageUIframework to your project 
and have these import in your interface file

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface Your CLass : UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

**Code**

```
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
    if ([mailClass canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [picker setSubject:@"Your Subject"];        

        NSFileManager* manager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init]; 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];   
        if (![[self NoteFile] isEqualToString:@""]) //check if note is blank
 {
            NSString *NoteFilePath = [documentsDirectory 
                                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",[self NoteFileName]]];
            NSData *myNoteData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:NoteFilePath];
            [picker addAttachmentData:myNoteData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"Name you want to give your file.txt"];
        }

        [manager release];


        // Fill out the email body text
        NSString *emailBody = @"I am attaching my file!";
        [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];


        [picker release];
```

You can further check the mail status using its delegate methods

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
```